# Keep or Replace Matrix Elements Given Conditions for Two Different Matrices

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have two very long 1D-matrices (here represented by the much shorter x and y matrices). I would like to create two new matrices X and Y that I will plot against each other given the following two conditions:

In both matrices, I want to keep the element values of the indices where x < 7 and y != -9999 and I want to replace all other element values with the flag value -9999.

Currently, I can achive this by a very slow loop:

```
# Create some fake data:
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(0, 100, 10)
y[2] = -9999.0
y[5] = -9999.0
y[8] = -9999.0

x
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

y
array([0, 10, -9999, 30, 40, -9999, 60, 70, -9999, 90])

# Loop over the data
for idx in np.arange(10):
    # Keep matrice elements in both matrices satisfying:
    if x[idx] < 7 and y != -9999:
        x[idx] = [idx]
        y[idx] = y[idx]
    # Replace all other elements with the flag -9999
    else:
        x[idx] = -9999
        y[idx] = -9999 

x
array([0, 1, -9999, 3, 4, -9999, 6, -9999, -9999, -9999])

y
array([0, 10, -9999, 30, 40, -9999, 60, -9999, -9999, -9999])


x_rm_flags = filter(lambda a: a != -9999.0, x)  # Removes all flagged values == -9999.0, thus shorting the matrix and converts it into a list
X = np.zeros([len(x_rm_flags),1])               # Convert the list into an array. Step 1: Create the (zero-)array
X[:,0] = x_rm_flags[:]                          # Convert the list into an array. Step 2: Fill the array with its correct values

y_rm_flags = filter(lambda a: a != -9999.0, y)  # Removes all flagged values == -9999.0, thus shorting the matrix and converts it into a list
Y = np.zeros([len(y_rm_flags),1])               # Convert the list into an array. Step 1: Create the (zero-)array
Y[:,0] = y_rm_flags[:]                          # Convert the list into an array. Step 2: Fill the array with its correct values
```

What I would want is to do what the loop does, but in a much more efficient way and I was hoping that python might have some built in function for this. (For example, I considered using numpy.where and/or numpy.select, but I haven't been able to figure out how to implement and use these - if they are even a good way to go about it.)

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can make my code more efficient?

Comment: try index and slice: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: @Wending Peng Thank you for your answer! It gave me some pointers, but it didn't contain any examples which I could implement directly into my code.